# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'StageOne.__init__' was never awaited (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, asyncio, async-await

Всех приветствую.

У меня есть два файла. В первом у меня описана команда для Discord-бота, а во втором классы с кнопками и сообщениями для этого бота.

Файл с командой:

```
@app_commands.command(name="verification-admin", description="Команды верификации для администраторов")
    @app_commands.choices(action=[
        app_commands.Choice(name="setup", value="setup"),
        app_commands.Choice(name="set-questions", value="set-questions"),
        app_commands.Choice(name="remove", value="remove")
    ])
    async def verifadmin(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, action: app_commands.Choice[str]):
        if await permchecker(interaction=interaction):
            if action.value == "setup":
                connection = pymysql.connect(host=db_ip, port=db_port, user=db_user, password=db_password, database=db_name)
                cursor = connection.cursor()
                cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `s_verification` WHERE `server_id` = %s;", (interaction.guild.id,))
                if cursor.rowcount != 0:
                    cursor.fetchall()
                    await interaction.response.send_message("У вас уже произведена установка верификации. \nЧтобы сбросить её, пропишите `/verification remove`\nЧтобы изменить настройки верификации, пропишите команду `/settings` и долистайте до страницы настроек верификации.", ephemeral=True)
                    return
                else: 
                    # Класс, импортирующийся из второго файла
                    await StageOne(interaction=interaction, bot=self.bot)

            else:
                await interaction.response.send_message("Ещё не готово.", ephemeral=True)
                return
```

Класс из второго файла (StageOne):

```
class StageOne(discord.ui.View): # Приветствие
    async def __init__(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, bot: commands.Bot):
        await super().__init__()
        self.bot = bot
        self.data = [].append(interaction.guild_id)
        embed = EmbedGen.VerifSetup.stageOne()
        
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=self)
        await interaction.response.defer()

    @discord.ui.button(label="Далее >", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def stageone(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        if await permchecker(interaction):
            await StageTwo(interaction=interaction, data=self.data, bot=self.bot)
            del self
```

И когда я пытаюсь использовать эту команду, мне выводится ошибка в консоли. В ответ на саму команду ничего не происходит.

```
/home/den/vbot/cogs/verification.py:42: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'StageOne.__init__' was never awaited
  await StageOne(interaction=interaction, bot=self.bot)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
2023-04-21 15:26:18 ERROR    discord.app_commands.tree Ignoring exception in command 'verification-admin'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/den/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 841, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(self.binding, interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/den/vbot/cogs/verification.py", line 42, in verifadmin
    await StageOne(interaction=interaction, bot=self.bot)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'coroutine'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/den/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1248, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "/home/den/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 867, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/den/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 856, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'verification-admin' raised an exception: TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'coroutine'
```

Как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: Сделать __init__ синхронным, а логику в нем вынести в отдельный асинхронный метод.

Comment: `__init__` не должен быть асинхронным. В нем нужно оставить синхронную инициализацию, а все асинхронное вынести в отдельный асинхронный метод, и дергать его через await.

Comment: Да, это помогло. Спасибо огромное!